# Label names within Manipulate with ControlType->RadioButton

Tags: manipulate

I modified an example from the documentation to have a `RadioButton` control over a specific list of values:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}], {{a, 2, "Multiplier"}, {1, 2}}, {{b, 
   3, "Phase Parameter"}, {3, 4, 5}}, ControlType -> RadioButton]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, in place of 1, 2, 3, etc. I'd like textual labels (but still need to pass those specific, discrete numeric values to the object inside the `Manipulate`).

In the spirit of the *Multiplier* textual label, I tried

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}], 
  {{a, 2, "Multiplier"}, {{1, "cat"}, {2, "dog"}}}, 
  {{b, 3, "Phase Parameter"}, {3, 4, 5}}, ControlType -> RadioButton]
```

to no avail:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How do I get the appearance (and behavior) here that I am after?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `RadioButtonBar` which allows labeling of the values:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}], 
 {{a, 1, "Multiplier"}, {1 -> "cat",  2 -> "dog"}}, 
 {{b, 3, "Phase Parameter"}, {3, 4, 5}},  ControlType -> RadioButtonBar]
```

[image]

or

```
 Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x + b] /. {"cat" -> 1, "dog" -> 2}, {x, 0, 6}], 
  {{a,  "cat", "Multiplier"}, {"cat", "dog"}}, 
   {{b, 3, "Phase Parameter"}, {3, 4, 5}}, ControlType -> RadioButton]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[c*Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}], {{a, 1, "Multiplier"}, {1 -> "cat", 
   2 -> "dog"}, RadioButton}, {{b, 3, "Phase Parameter"}, {3, 4, 5}, 
  RadioButton}, {{c, 1, "Peak Amplitude"}, InputField}]
```

I like using this setup allowing for a variety of `Manipulate` controls.

Comment: Does this work for Mma8?

Comment: I'm running the code in Mathematica 8 and it works.